# Why do some objects appear transparent?

Tags: transparency

Sometimes the objects I create, in this case, a plane that I filled from vertices, appear transparent. When I create them again from scratch, they don't. Does anyone know why this would be?

Furthermore, I can't use the edge tool with them either, but with a created plane, the edge loop tool works perfectly. Can anyone help?[image: image showing excessive transparency]

Comment: if you have not enabled the Backface Culling in the Viewport Shading panel, it looks like a bug

Comment: When I enable backface culling, the item disappears entirely! Surely this can't be a bug for every blender user? To add, this problem is only apparent in x-ray mode

Comment: could you please share your file? https://blend-exchange.com/

Comment: Shared: [<img src="https://blend-exchange.com/embedImage.png?bid=kgk58dwk" />](https://blend-exchange.com/b/kgk58dwk/)

Comment: Wrong Face Normal orientation ...

Comment: well actually you're in transparent mode and as Vklidu says the face can be almost invisible depending on its orientation

Comment: BTW those faces are not transparent more than others (in this X-Ray view), it is just an illusion - since blender is showing it as opposite side in shade, this shaded color is just similar to bg color so it looks like transparent.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just to clarify the two comments above with images:

Uncheck <kbd>x-ray</kbd> <kbd>mode</kbd> using <kbd>Alt-Z</kbd> or by clicking the icon marked with the arrow top-right. Then check <kbd>Face Orientation</kbd> on the <kbd>Overlays</kbd> menu.

[image]

The red face on your object shows that the normals are inverted so in Edit mode, select All then hit <kbd>Alt-N</kbd> > <kbd>Flip Normals</kbd> as shown below.

[image]

You'll now see that your object looks normal:

[image]

Comment: That's worked! Super, thank you so much for the explanation!

Comment: No problem. Please mark my answer as accepted.